# Different background shades in a single vim window

Tags: vim

In a single VIM window with 4 or 5 buffers for example, is it possible to give each buffer a different background shade?

Let's assume that the color theme is darkblue, I would like to make each buffer have a slightly different background shade of the dark blue.

Comment: It's not possible for the background, but there is StatusLineNC for StatusLine of non-current split. I think change that to something really pop like orange would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the colorscheme settings are global.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
:hi ColorColumn guibg=#550000
```

and then color the background of selected windows with:

```
:setlocal colorcolumn=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256
```

Unfortunately this will only give you two shades (the one you set and the default), and `colorcolumn`'s limit of 256 columns will break the illusion on very wide windows or long wrapped lines.

Thanks to [blueyed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15690/blueyed) for [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415828/vim-dim-inactive-split-panes#12519572).