# vim - dim inactive split panes

Tags: vim, iterm2

If you're familiar with the iTerm2 application, you'll know that you can split views similar to vim, and the inactive views are "dimmed."

I usually work in vim with three vertical split views and it would be nice to dim the inactive ones by setting the background color to a darker tone, for example.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have come up with the following solution (using 'colorcolumn' and unsetting 'cursorline'):

```
" Dim inactive windows using 'colorcolumn' setting
" This tends to slow down redrawing, but is very useful.
" Based on https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/IJU-Vk-QLJE/xz4hjPjCRBUJ
" XXX: this will only work with lines containing text (i.e. not '~')
function! s:DimInactiveWindows()
  for i in range(1, tabpagewinnr(tabpagenr(), '$'))
    let l:range = ""
    if i != winnr()
      if &wrap
        " HACK: when wrapping lines is enabled, we use the maximum number
        " of columns getting highlighted. This might get calculated by
        " looking for the longest visible line and using a multiple of
        " winwidth().
        let l:width=256 " max
      else
        let l:width=winwidth(i)
      endif
      let l:range = join(range(1, l:width), ',')
    endif
    call setwinvar(i, '&colorcolumn', l:range)
  endfor
endfunction
augroup DimInactiveWindows
  au!
  au WinEnter * call s:DimInactiveWindows()
  au WinEnter * set cursorline
  au WinLeave * set nocursorline
augroup END
```

View it at my (current) dotfiles: https://github.com/blueyed/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc#L351

**Update**
I have created a plugin out of it: https://github.com/blueyed/vim-diminactive

Comment: This might be made more efficient for any machines which are struggling.  We don't really need to run for all windows every time we switch window.  We just need to perform the `setwinvar` on any window we WinLeave, and `setlocal nocolorcolumn` on WinEnter.  (That is assuming our session starts with just one window, and we never create multiple windows without entering each of them.)

Comment: @AndyRay
I have created a plugin out of it: https://github.com/blueyed/vim-diminactive

Comment: I also knocked up a quick-and-dirty plugin, based on your answer: https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.vim/plugin/dim_inactive_windows.vim

Comment: @joeytwiddle cool! Would have been good to now, before I've created mine. I would appreciate a pull request, if you want to merge your changes (e.g. ignoring some buftypes, via config).

Comment: @blueyed There is almost nothing novel in mine, but of course I will contribute in future if I find any improvements; it's neat that you made a repo.  There are three limitations which I image you also suffer: 1. Really long wrapped lines don't get dimmed past column 256.  2. Out-of-bound lines aka "~" lines don't get dimmed.  3. The cursorline highlight masks any useful background highlighting you might have on dimmed windows (e.g. the last cope line in QuickFix, or the current tag line in TagList).  I could disable dimming on those windows too, but then only edit windows will be dimmed!

Comment: As of 2023 there is the `wincolor` option that does the job

Answer (score 12):

Throwing this out there as a new answer. https://github.com/TaDaa/vimade fades inactive buffers, preserves syntax highlighting, and can also fade signs.  I am the author, but I figure this might be useful to some as a newer alternative. Supports nvim and vim8, 256 color terminals, termguicolors, and gui.

Comment: Tried it, loved it, using it. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

In neovim(v0.2.1), the following configuration will dim inactive panes:

```
hi ActiveWindow ctermbg=16 | hi InactiveWindow ctermbg=233
set winhighlight=Normal:ActiveWindow,NormalNC:InactiveWindow
```

Comment: Just wanted to add: If you use nvim in a GUI (e.g nvim-qt), replace `ctermbg` with `guibg` and use a hex color as a value, e.g.  `guibg=#E7E7E7`.

Comment: I think there's a misconception here, you need not use winhighlight at all with neovim, the Normal and NormalNC highlight groups are all you need to specify separate nonactive window background color. You use winhighlight when you want to set different highlight state on specific windows.

Comment: I have built this into [walh](https://github.com/casonadams/walh) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the background colour as you describe would require different colourschemes for different Vim windows. As far as I know this is not possible, as it is a global setting (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8386438/575497) from a few days ago).

As a visual aid to which window is active, I find the statusline is usally sufficient. The highlight groups are different for the active window (`hi StatusLine`) and any innactive windows (`hi StatusLineNC`). You could either choose a colourscheme with a very stark constrast between them, or edit your favourite colourscheme.

Comment: In addition to a contrasting StatusLine, I find it helpful to set a CursorLine that stands out.

Comment: Although this is the answer accepted by the OP, it's actually incorrect. The answer by @blueyed provides a script which, placed in my .vimrc, does effectively change the background colour of inactive buffers (windows). It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, the `wincolor` might be what you're asking for. It sets the background color (the real background color, not `hl-Normal`) for a window.

Just add these lines to your vimrc

```
" dim inactive window
hi WindowInactive ctermbg=243  # or ctermbg=grey, in case you're not using an 256 color terminal
au VimEnter,WinNew,WinEnter   * set wincolor=
au WinLeave * set wincolor=WindowInactive
```

The result looks like
[image: alt]

Answer (score 0):

I created a colorscheme [walh](https://github.com/casonadams/walh) that handles this.

It doesn't do many fancy things, it just uses the terminal colors to do the highlights and dimming.  This is nice because if you use `tmux` that dimming will match.

Looks something like this `nvim|nvim(focus)|tmux` :
[image]