# Vim: set background color for non-textedit windows (NERDTree or Tagbar for example)

Tags: vim

Is there any way to set background color for specific windows (quickfix window, NERDTree, Tagbar...) ?
I've found that it's possible for columns at the left side (line number, sign or fold), so I wonder is there a possibility to do same with non-editable windows

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415828/) does not solve the problem: it makes a colorscheme for a *whole* vim, but I need a window-local color.

Found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415828/), but it has problem with Tagbar window

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get different colorschemes in Vim split window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062491/how-to-get-different-colorschemes-in-vim-split-window)